# react native video display thumbnail before video is played

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-video

I am using react-native-video for displaying videos to the user [react-native-video-controls](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video-controls) for showing controls. My aim is to show the thumbnail before the video is played. This thumbnails are images stored in the server. But I am not getting how to display this thumbnails in react native video component.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance

here is the code

import Video from 'react-native-video';
import VideoPlayer from 'react-native-video-controls';

```
const App = () => {

  return (
    <>

       <VideoPlayer
        source={{ uri: 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4' }}
        ref={(ref) => {
          // console.log(ref)
          setData(ref)
        }}
        style={styles.backgroundVideo}
        onBuffer={onBuffer}                // Callback when remote video is buffering
        onError={videoError}               // Callback when video cannot be loaded
        fullscreen={true}
        resizeMode="contain"
        paused = {true}
      /> 


    </>

}
```

Answer (score 3):

the way I went about this was to have each video object include its URI and a thumbnail field.

then include a condition when the video component is in its paused state, the thumbnail should be displayed with a higher zIndex.

note the paused condition & the video component should be in the same view.

here's a code sample:
`{paused && (

<Image
source={{uri:'thumbnailuri'}}
style={{flex: 1,
backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
position: 'absolute',
resizeMode: 'cover',
height: '100%',
width: '100%',
zIndex: 10,

```js
{paused && (
                <View style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
                    position: 'absolute',
                    resizeMode: 'cover',
                    zIndex: 10,
                    height: '100%',
                    width: '100%',
                    }>
                  <Image
                    source={{
                      uri:'thumbnailuri'
                    }}
                    style={{
                    height: '100%',
                    width: '100%',
                    }
                  />
                </View>
              )}
```

hope this was helpful.

Comment: I got it (mostly) working with this approach, except I had to use {videoPause ? ( /* thumbnail code */) : null}

Comment: glad it was helpful, yeah showing the image component instead of the video also works

Answer (score 0):

There is a poster attribute for videos, not sure if video player "Component will supoort it.

```
poster="https://somesite/thumb.png""
```

Syntax :

```
<video height="" width="" poster="URL of the image to be displayed">
```

*Sidenote: For youtube thumbnails are accesible by below url schemes.

For the default & normal quality thumbnail:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<youtube-video-id>/default.jpg
```

For the high quality (HQ) thumbnail:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<youtube-video-id>/hqdefault.jpg
```

Comment: Actually I have gone through poster prop. It displayed an image only when the video is loading. See here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video#poster. So it doesn't work for me

Comment: And the second point  this are not youtube videos. So can't use their thumbnail